# Trying To Make A Code Generator input-preset output in powershell windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

im trying to make a powershell code generator what i want is for

```
$input = read-host ""
```

to be used to compare to `$Alpha = "a","B" etc`
then output to

```
write-host
```

the equal form from `$Beta = "T","C" etc`
the thought is that im trying to create a digital version of something like a decoder ring but in powershell

Comment: So you just want to "encode" and "decode" messages in PowerShell? Is that what you're asking? Your question seems to have confused me.

Comment: essentially yes

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your exact requirements but you said in your comments you are looking to encode and decode messages in PowerShell.

The below will convert the users input into Base64 and then decode it again.

```
$UserInput = Read-Host
$EncodedText = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($UserInput))
"This is the encoded text: $($EncodedText)" | Write-Host

$DecodedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncodedText))
"This is the decoded text: $($DecodedText)" | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Drew, but tweaking his helpful answer a bit:

If all you are doing is sending the text to the screen, always, then for this the use case you don't need Write-Host at all. You can use PowerShell Variabel Squeezing. Get input and assign it to the variable and output to screen at the same time. Like the Pipe '|' the double colon is a natural line continuation option (as are many including comparison operators). Though not commonly used this way.

```
"This is the encoded text: $(($EncodedText = [Convert]::
                            ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::
                            Unicode.GetBytes($(Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a string')))))"
"This is the decoded text: $([System.Text.Encoding]::
                            Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::
                            FromBase64String($EncodedText)))"
# Results
<#
Enter a string: test
This is the encoded text: dABlAHMAdAA=
This is the decoded text: test
#>
```

Comment: ok this is close to what im looking for but i want the output to be the same length as the input while the output is like this {input = test, output = {t=a, e=s, s=z, t=f}} but it comes out as "aszf" when encoded

Comment: So, you only want a script to use chars [A-z..a-z] randomized string assignment, based on inputs and then reverse that? If so, then that is really not a PowerShell code issue/problem, but a project specifc use goal. The rules on SO are: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You'll often get the notice/comment 'SO is not script writing service.' or 'You need to show us your work.'

Comment: Also if my last comment is what you are after, then it's not hard to do at all. It's just a matter of setting up a seedstring range array for your encode and using the New-Variable cmdlet to work the input, and parsing as needed for your results for decode.